# Neo4j : Two different relationships with same name

Tags: graph, neo4j

**Scenario 1:**

**Model:**

`User` -[:FOLLOW]-> `User`

`User` -[:FOLLOW]-> `Playlist`

`FOLLOW` relationship between two `User`s has attribute `followerType` which represents how a user is following other user e.g. a user can follow other user via twitter or via google plus.


`FOLLOW` relationship between a `User` and a `Playlist` shouldn't have any `followerType` attribute because here it doesn't mean anything. This relationship simply represents that the user should be notified of any changes in the playlist e.g. addition of song, removal of song etc.

**Question:** In this kind of scenario, shall we give different names to both the relationships to differentiate one from other or Is there any other way to handle this?

---

**Scenario 2:**

**Model:**

`User` -[:PLAYED]-> `Song`

`User` -[:PLAYED]-> `Playlist`

**Question:** In this kind of scenario, both `PLAYED` relationships represents same action but applied on two different types of nodes `Song` and `Playlist`. So is this a good idea to treat both the relationships as same or treat them differently by assigning different names e.g. `PLAYED_SONG` and `PLAYED_PLAYLIST`?

Answer (score 2):

It depends ;)

If you want to distinguish the difference at query time it is "cheaper" to have a different type. For example:

```
match (:User)-[:PLAYED_SONG]->()
```

will the cheaper than:

```
match (:User)-[:PLAYED]->(:Song)
```

Because Neo4j only have to look at the relationship type, Instead of relationship type and node Label.

If you want to have both Songs and Playlists for example:

```
match (:User)-[:PLAYED]->()
```

Will be must easier to understand than:

```
match (:User)-[:PLAYED_SONG|PLAYED_PLAYLIST]->()
```

My suggestion would be to go for the FOLLOW and PLAYED as type. Do some performance tests with that setup.